# the better url for a API: /api or api

Tags: rest, api

when you make a API, what is a better practice ?

```
http://webapp/api
```

or

```
http://api.webapp/
```

why ?

I started with the API in `http://webapp/api` and the description of the service in `http://webapp`. but now, I would like separate the description of the API in differents repositories, for this reason, I'm thinking in change the url API to `http://api.webapp/`.

is a good idea/practice ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One benefit of `http://webapp/api` is that if you are developing the web site and the api as part of the same code base, you don't really need to do any special handling to deploy the api - it's just one web application that you have to deploy.

If you did use `api.webapp`, for this case, then you would probably have to do some special handling during initial setup of the application.

For `http://api.webapp/` on the other hand, you use a different host name in the url (assuming you also have a web application running at `http://webapp/`).

This means that it could point to a different IP address - or it could point to the same IP - depending on DNS configuration. So by using this, you could have the api and web application be served by the same physical server to begin with, and later have the option of separating the two, *without breaking your public interface!*

So the first could be easier to setup initially, the latter gives you more options.